# Bootstrap FOOTER fixed

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, footer

my problem is the following:

On mobile devices my fixed footer overlaps with the content of the page so I can't click a button because the footer is on top.

Here's the code and a picture:

```
<nav class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-right">
        <span class="label label-default">Freier Speicher: 20 mb</span>
    </div>
    <p class="copyright small text-center">&copy; 2016/2017 Juan Carlos Velarde, Ludwig Stengelin</p>
    <p class="small text-center"> Icons from <a href="https://icons8.com/">Icons8</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Hope you can help me :) And thanks for taking the time to comment :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a bottom margin (equal to the height of your footer) to your body element.

```
body {
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
```